# getting a value in XPATH when only I know something about it descendants?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xpath

Imagine a xml file like this:

```
<Document>
   <Tests>
      <Test>
          <Name>A</Name>
          <SubTest>
              <Test>
                 <Name>B</Name>
                 <Value>100</Value>
              </Test>
           </SubTest>
       </Test>
      <Test>
          <Name>C</Name>
          <SubTest>
              <Test>
                 <Name>D</Name>
                 <Value>200</Value>
              </Test>
           </SubTest>
       </Test>
    </Tests> 
</Document>
```

I use a method to access the `B` value, but I need to get name `A` as well, but I only now that value `B` exist in my XML file (`doc` is `XmlDocument`):

```
public class TestData
{
public string Parent {get;set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
public int Value {get;set;} 
}

private TestData GetResult(string name)
{
   TestData data = new TestData();
   data.Name = name;
   data.Value = 
   int.Parse(doc.SelectSingleNode("Document/Tests/Test/SubTest/Test[Name = '" + name + "']/Value").InnerText);

   data.Parent = null; //How can I get string A using the above xpath   

   return data;
}
```

So, the question is, how can I access `A` in the above method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this XPath:

```
Document/Tests/Test[SubTest/Test/Name = 'B']/Name
```

or:

```
var nodeTest = 
    doc.SelectSingleNode("Document/Tests/Test[SubTest/Test/Name = 'B']");

var name = nodeTest.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText;
var value = nodeTest.SelectSingleNode("SubTest/Test/Value").InnerText;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the xpath expression to read A:

```
/Document/Tests/Test[Subtest/Test/Name = 'B']/Name
```